# Cannot find symbol `asIterator()`

Tags: java, iterator

I have a file, `adapter/new/myAdapter.java`

```
package adapter.new;
import adapter.old.Person;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class GroupAdapter implements Group {

    private adapter.old.Group oldgroup;

    public GroupAdapter(adapter.old.Group oldgroup) {
        this.oldgroup = oldgroup;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Person> getPersons() {
      return new Iterable<Person>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Person> iterator() {
          return oldgroup.getPersons().asIterator();
        }
      };
    }
}
```

This is my `adapter/old/Group.java`

```
package adapter.old;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Group {
  private String number;
  private String name;
  private Vector<Person> persons;

  public Group(String number, String name) {
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name
    persons = new Vector<>();
  }

  public Enumeration<Person> getPersons() {
    return persons.elements();
  }  
}
```

When I try compiling this:

```
javac old/*.java new/*.java
```

I get this error:

```
new/GroupAdapter.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
          return oldgroup.getPersons().asIterator();
                                       ^
  symbol:   method asIterator()
  location: interface Enumeration<Person>
1 error
```

What am I doing wrong? I followed a tutorial, more or less, but I can't find out where I went wrong.

Comment: Enumeration.asIterator() exists since Java 9. Which version of Java do you use?

Comment: @JBNizet When I do `java -version` in terminal, it says `openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)`. Am I importing it correctly?

Comment: What does `javac -version` say?

Comment: @JBNizet `javac 1.8.0_144`

Comment: So you have your answer...

Comment: @JBNizet on my other machine it says `javac 1.8.0_222`

Comment: That's still Java 8. And asIterator() has been introduced in Java 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asIterator method was added to Enumeration class in java9. Check the version of javac you are using.

[Enumeration javadoc java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)

[Enumeration javadoc java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)

Comment: when I do `java -version` in terminal, it says `openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)` Am I importing it correctly?

Comment: Not `java -version`, `javac -version` (note the c for the compiler). @user2719875

Comment: You're sure `package adapter.new;` doesn't emit a compile error?